# xamarin.mac hello world outlet null reference

Tags: xamarin-studio

I downloaded the sample xamarin.mac hello world project and when I try to run I get a null reference exception on the outletes when it runs.  I see the outlets get properties set to them in the MainWindow.designer.cs partial classes but when it tries to reference them in MainWindowController.cs a null reference exception is thrown.

How does the sample project work when the property definitions are in the MainWindow.cs partial class and not in the controller class.  Is the sample project supposed to work out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the hello world example, but I come across this problem all the time in native Mac/Xcode land and I just hit it again inside Xamarin Studio. My problem happened to be this: I have a GUI full of NSTextFields. I wired each in turn to a new outlet in MainWindowController.h, however I accidentally re-wired the second NSTextField in my list to the outet I'd previously defined for the first TextField. This automatically disconnects the previous link, and even though the outlet remains defined in the .h, the connection in the .xib is broken and thus the first outlet never gets initialized with the xib's NSTextField instance.

The solution is basically right-click the GUI element in question in interface builder and be sure its referencing outlet is actually wired up to the outlet you expect in the .h.